# Sci Fi short story about characters exploring an alternate pocket universe

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, parallel-universe, hard-sci-fi

Sci Fi short story I found in an anthology.

I think the story dates back to at least the 1990's.

I believe the characters are exploring an alternate pocket universe.

They require special suits to survive.

To navigate the universe requires repeating unusual behaviors in a specific sequence, any deviation is fatal, but there's some kind of reboot mechanism.

Once the explorer has reached the furthest above has ever gone, they have to try, through the process of elimination, the next arbitrary action that allows advancement. Generally they die.

At least one part of the narrative describes the actions an explorer repeats to get to the farthest destination yet, and I believe they "skip" "hop" "twist" and "jump".

I believe the characters are American, with the protagonist an officer in the military.

I don't remember the ending.

Comment: There are two novels that use this idea, [Rogue Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_Moon) and [The Man in the Maze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_in_the_Maze_(novel)).

Comment: Possibly Alastair Reynolds' "Diamond Dogs"?

Comment: Indeed Rogue Moon! TY!

Comment: Diamond Dogs was good. I did start and put down Man in the Maze once I realized it wasn't the story I sought.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This could be *[Rogue Moon](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1285)* by Algis Budrys, published in 1960.

The story concerns an alien labyrinth on the Moon. In order to progress through it, an explorer has to performs sets of completely arbitrary signs and gestures. For example:

> It is, for example, fatal to kneel on one knee while facing Lunar
> north. It is fatal to raise the left hand above shoulder height while
> in any position whatsoever. It is fatal past a certain point to wear
> armor whose airhoses loop over the shoulders. It is fatal past another
> point to wear armor whose air tanks feed directly into the suit
> without the use of hoses at all. It is crippling to wear armor whose
> dimensions vary greatly from the ones we are using now. It is fatal to
> use the arm motions required to write the English word ‘yes/ either
> with the left or right hand.

If they fail to follow the actions precisely, the structure kills them. In order to make progress, the explorers are sent to the Moon via a matter transporter, while remaining on Earth in a state of sensory deprivation that allows them to share the experiences of their doppelganger and so assemble the list of actions required to unlock each trap. When the transported version dies, however, it is very disturbing for the original, and only one explorer, Barker, was able to retain his sanity after his double was killed.

In particular, one of the traps is dealt with by making a set of moves that Barker describes as:

> "I dodge, and duck, and twist, and inch, and spring, and wait for
> the—the—...

which resembles the description given by the OP.

As noted by DavidW in comments, a shortened version of the novel was published in *F&SF* in December 1960. This is available from the Internet Archive [here](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v019n06_1960-12_PDF/page/n3/mode/2up), and was also published in Bova's *[Science Fiction Hall of Fame Volume IIB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?221621)* in 1973.

Comment: Note, since OP describes a short story, that Budrys also published a cut-down [novella length version](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56691) that was collected in Bova's  [*Science Fiction Hall of Fame*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?8293) series.

Comment: Well spotted! Added the link now.

Comment: I've always wondered which came first.

Comment: Thank you all.A sleepless few hours await.

Comment: Thanks so much!